# Is it possible to use CREATE2 without going through the Smart Contract's function?

Tags: evm, create2

EIP-1014 was the standard that added the CTEATE2 Opcode (0xf5).

Is there any way to use 0xf5 other than calling the SmartContract's inline-assembly function?

Answer (score 1):

To utilize `CREATE2` without directly calling a smart contract's inline assembly function, you typically need to interact with the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) or use libraries that provide this functionality indirectly.

Comment: Can you recommend any libraries for reference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's similar to the CREATE method, you just need to specify the salt. See the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.23/control-structures.html#salted-contract-creations-create2) for details.

Example:

```
// CREATE
ChildContract newContract = new ChildContract(args);

// CREATE2
ChildContract newContract = new ChildContract{salt: salt}(args);
```